# Chords in Moonlight Sonata 1st movement

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-progressions, analysis

From [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNBm9wD9zg0):

1. In 1st measure - first chord - it's said that it is  C#min (i) but there are  C-C#-G.
   I thought it should be  C#-E-G#  why is it C#min (i) if there are C-C#-G??
2. In 3st measure - first chord - it's said that it is  A (VI) but there are  A-A-A.
   I thought it should be  A-C#-E  why is it A (VI) if there are  A-A-A??
3. In some measures (i.e. 4,12,13,25,48 etc.) there are 3 or 4 chords in one measure.
   I thought, in general, chords could change only on strong beats(except for syncopation).
   Does that mean there's a syncopation in there or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a problem right away in the way you are looking at the analysis. When you analyze something and notate either a chord or a Roman numeral the chord is meant to analyze all notes and pitches up to the next chord/Roman numeral change with the exception of a few non-harmonic tones that are typically notated. Also note you are in the key of C# minor so the notes F,C,G, and D are sharp [unless otherwise noted](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17389/is-a-high-a-in-the-key-of-d-flat-still-flat/17390#17390).

1. The notes in the first measure are two C# notes in the lower staff and G#,
   C#, and E in the top staff. This does in fact make a C#m chord.
2. The notes in the first half of measure 3 are two A notes in the lower staff and A,
   C#, and E in the top staff. This does in fact make a A major chord.
3. It is typical to speed up the [harmonic rhythm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_rhythm) as you approach cadences. At every place you mention there being more chords I see a cadence so this is a very typical and expected pattern. I wouldn't call any part of this syncopation because even though the chords are changing at a faster rate, they are still changing on predictable on the beat fashion even though it is sometimes the weak beat. In syncopation, there would be chord changes that are off-beat which is different.