# If a note is raised in a measure, does it mean the other notes of the same pitch are also raised?

Tags: sheet-music

Sorry if this is a bad question, the music *reads* like this

A  #F  D  F  A  F  D  F

now you can see only the first F is raised, but on the piece is actually played with all Fs' of that measure raised. Is this just a bad composer, or am i simply missing something?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zxQajHf      The second measure is the measure in question

Comment: I imagine the word needed is **accidental** rather than *accented* - they're very different meanings , particularly in music.

Comment: ...and FYI “accented” refers to a note being played with emphasis or louder than other notes, uses the symbol >  and only applies to the individual note it is written on.

Answer (score 0):

Any **accidental** - usually a sharp, flat or natural which is contrary to the key signature - will relate to that note , at that pitch only, for the rest of that bar, unless cancelled by a subsequent accidental referring to that same note.

Comment: by "bar" do you mean for the rest of the piece, until another accidental  is placed on that key?

EDIT: nvm i got, big thank you!

Comment: No. the vertical lines are barlines, so between any two lines there's one bar. The very next barline annuls any accidentals in that actual bar, so they don't carry on to the next. If needed again, they must be re-written.

Comment: It should be "on that *line* only", right?  Incidentally, I read that from your answer [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/107706/does-the-natural-sign-still-apply-with-the-octave-up-sign)

Comment: @Edward - if the affectected note is on a line, yes. If it's in a space, then the same applies.If there's another F, higher or lower, the accidental does not affect that other one.